# Dynamic query with hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, dynamic

I'm trying to select object from dynamic tables but when I run my code I get some erros... There's a way for to do it... I'm using JPA, hibernate and postgres

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value =
                "SELECT u.* " +
                        "FROM " +
                        " ?1 AS u ")
    Map<String, String> findAny(String tableName);
```

Here is the error...

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
>       "debugMessage": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialec
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate, you can't set `table name` as `paramater`, this is to ensure against security risks like SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

you have to mentions the table that you are getting the data from

value ="SELECT * FROM TableName u ?1")